# How to get Specified XML node element in C# & Convert XML to Json in Jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, xml

I have an XML as shown below. I need to only get the child elements inside the "rs:data" node. So after i have gotten these elements, I need to convert them into JSON format using jQquery or Javascript.

```
<Response>
    <Request>
        <ConnectInfo>

        </ConnectInfo>
        <Method>
            <PARAMS>
            </PARAMS>
            <QueryControl>
            </QueryControl>
        </Method>
    </Request>
    <MethodResponse>
        <DeResult>
            <xml xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
                <rs:data>
                    <z:row BACKGROUND="" DOC.APP_FORMAT_TYPE="&lt;NO VALUE&gt;" DOC.AUTHOR="balakrishna" DOC.Access_UDF="Public" DOC.BOM_DEFINING="Yes" DOC.CAGE_CODE="CAGE_CODE1" DOC.CATEGORY_ID="000007" DOC.CATEGORY_NAME="doc" DOC.CLASSIFICATION="UNRESTRICTED" DOC.CREATE_DATE="08/29/2017" DOC.CUST_DOC_NO="" DOC.CUST_DOC_REV="" DOC.DATE_APPROVAL="" DOC.DATE_EFF_FROM="08/01/2017" DOC.DATE_EFF_THRU="FOREVER" DOC.DERIVED_FROM="" DOC.DERIVED_FROM_REV="" DOC.DOC_CLASS="&lt;NO VALUE&gt;" DOC.DOC_KEY="DOC-000000007" DOC.DOC_NAME=" ff" DOC.DOC_TYPE="COMMON" DOC.Destructive_Physical_Analysis="" DOC.EO_ID="" DOC.LIFE_CYCLE="LIFE_CYCLE1" DOC.MANUF_ID="" DOC.MPN="" DOC.NO_OF_ECN="" DOC.OBSOLETE="No" DOC.ORIGINATING_APP="PDM" DOC.PREV_REVISION="" DOC.PROJECT_ID="P1" DOC.REVISION="0001" DOC.STATUS="UNDEFINED" DOC.TAA="" DOC.UPDATE_DATE="10/06/2017" DOC.ZZ_ID="7"/>
                    <z:row BACKGROUND="#CCFFFF" DOC.APP_FORMAT_TYPE="IN Part" DOC.AUTHOR="de1" DOC.Access_UDF="&lt;Select Option&gt;" DOC.BOM_DEFINING="Yes" DOC.CAGE_CODE="CAGE_CODE1" DOC.CATEGORY_ID="" DOC.CATEGORY_NAME="" DOC.CLASSIFICATION="UNRESTRICTED" DOC.CREATE_DATE="08/29/2017" DOC.CUST_DOC_NO="" DOC.CUST_DOC_REV="" DOC.DATE_APPROVAL="08/29/2017" DOC.DATE_EFF_FROM="08/29/2017" DOC.DATE_EFF_THRU="FOREVER" DOC.DERIVED_FROM="" DOC.DERIVED_FROM_REV="" DOC.DOC_CLASS="&lt;NO VALUE&gt;" DOC.DOC_KEY="DOC-000000070" DOC.DOC_NAME="INV17--29-AUG-17-Part5.ipt" DOC.DOC_TYPE="COMMON" DOC.Destructive_Physical_Analysis="" DOC.EO_ID="" DOC.LIFE_CYCLE="LIFE_CYCLE1" DOC.MANUF_ID="" DOC.MPN="" DOC.NO_OF_ECN="" DOC.OBSOLETE="No" DOC.ORIGINATING_APP="Inventor" DOC.PREV_REVISION="" DOC.PROJECT_ID="P1" DOC.REVISION="0001" DOC.STATUS="UNDER_CHANGE" DOC.TAA="" DOC.UPDATE_DATE="" DOC.ZZ_ID="185"/>
                    <z:row BACKGROUND="" DOC.APP_FORMAT_TYPE="IN Part" DOC.AUTHOR="de1" DOC.Access_UDF="&lt;Select Option&gt;" DOC.BOM_DEFINING="Yes" DOC.CAGE_CODE="CAGE_CODE1" DOC.CATEGORY_ID="" DOC.CATEGORY_NAME="" DOC.CLASSIFICATION="UNRESTRICTED" DOC.CREATE_DATE="08/29/2017" DOC.CUST_DOC_NO="" DOC.CUST_DOC_REV="" DOC.DATE_APPROVAL="" DOC.DATE_EFF_FROM="08/29/2017" DOC.DATE_EFF_THRU="FOREVER" DOC.DERIVED_FROM="" DOC.DERIVED_FROM_REV="" DOC.DOC_CLASS="&lt;NO VALUE&gt;" DOC.DOC_KEY="DOC-000000070" DOC.DOC_NAME="INV17--29-AUG-17-Part5.ipt" DOC.DOC_TYPE="COMMON" DOC.Destructive_Physical_Analysis="" DOC.EO_ID="" DOC.LIFE_CYCLE="LIFE_CYCLE1" DOC.MANUF_ID="" DOC.MPN="" DOC.NO_OF_ECN="" DOC.OBSOLETE="No" DOC.ORIGINATING_APP="Inventor" DOC.PREV_REVISION="0001" DOC.PROJECT_ID="P1" DOC.REVISION="0002" DOC.STATUS="UNDEFINED" DOC.TAA="" DOC.UPDATE_DATE="08/29/2017" DOC.ZZ_ID="187"/>
                                    </rs:data>
            </xml>
        </DeResult>

    </MethodResponse>
</Response>
```

Thanks in advance for Help.

Comment: What have you tried to get that part? This is not a code writing service.

Comment: There were some English comprehension errors that were making it difficult to understand your question so i have corrected it for it to be clearly understandable.

Comment: I found answer by myself